# how can I read a defined variable in podfile

Tags: cocoapods

How can I read a defined variable in podfile? For example,

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
$myversion = ‘1.0’
target 'rubytest' do
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
end
```

`myversion` is the variable, in which module can I read it?

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly but the following example works for me.

```
FrameworkVersion = '= x.y.z'

target :Application do
  platform :ios, '8.0'
  pod 'Framework', FrameworkVersion
end
```

(CocoaPods version 1.2.1)